# SSRS disable subscription from reporting database

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I have a report subscription that throws an error when trying to view so I can't disable it, I have disabled it from the My Subscriptions screen on Report Manager but it is still being delivered.

I am thinking of disabling it from the reporting database, as it shows it is still running.

Has anyone done this or know how best to do this?

Comment: Disable the job in Agent.

Comment: @Larnu Do you mean SQL Agent? The job doesn't exist there, it's a subscription on Report Manager. If there is something that can be done in SQL Agent please elaborate.

Comment: When you create a sub scruoption in the Report Manager, in SSRS, it creates a job in SQL Server Agent.

Comment: I've had a look at JobScheduleID, JobStartStepName in SQL Server agent and other fields and I can't track the precise job that needs disabling. They are mostly named with hash characters. KNow how to find it, there are 500 subscriptions.

Comment: The job it makes has the same id as the subscription. So if the subscription's ID is D3C65C74-2FE2-4998-82B9-9330082EAC2F, then so too will be the job.

Comment: I searched for that sub id but it didn't exist, in the end I did the following .......

update [ReportServer].[dbo].[Subscriptions]
set [InactiveFlags] = '128'
,[LastStatus] = 'Disabled'

  where Report_OID = '5BD8C764-9276-4507-971B-DD21074664B3'
   and SubscriptionID = 'E9197EF3-AA9C-4810-918B-D480FAD0CD3C'
   go